# BOOTMGR is missing error in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bootmgr, ntldr

On an old netbook I have which is (was) running Windows XP, and when I boot, I get a `BOOTMGR is missing` error, but according to [this site](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/bootmgr-is-missing.htm) I should actually get `NTLDR is missing` instead. I find this vexing. Is there a fix for it? (Exact error: `BOOTMGR is missing (newline) Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart`)

Comment: Does the drive appear in the bios IDE menu pages? If this happened randomly, without any software changes, it's likely the hard drive isn't visible to the bios - either because of loose cables (like the link mentions) or a physically damaged drive. If you can boot from a USB CD/DVD drive, and you know the hard drive is physically ok, you can fix the boot files using a windows install CD in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message usually indicates that the boot sector is damaged or missing. The boot sector is a region of your hard disk that contains information that is used to load your operating system. If a boot failure is detected when your PC is starting, you may receive this error message.

To resolve this issue, use the steps in the following KB article:

[You receive Error message: “Bootmgr is missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart” when starting Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2622803)

Comment: BOOTMGR Errors Apply To BOOTMGR issues apply to Windows 7 and Windows Vista operating systems only. Windows XP does not utilize BOOTMGR. The equivalent function in Windows XP is NTLDR.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm confused